Homotopy equivalence is weak equivalence in model categories
For the following, we work in a model category $C$ (with functorial factorizations, though I'm not sure if it's needed).
In Hovey's Model Categories Theorem 1.2.10.ii it is stated that if $X$ is cofibrant and $Y$ is fibrant, then there is a natural isomorphism $\text{Ho}C(X,Y) \cong C(X,Y)/\sim$, with $\sim$ being the homotopy relation. He just says that this follows from previous results, but I've been unable to show this. I think I could show this in an elementary way but I want to follow his argument.
What I do understand is that we have an equivalence $\text{Ho}C \simeq C_{cf}$, and so a natural isomorphism $\text{Ho}C(X,Y) \cong C(QRX,QRY)/\sim$, but there doesn't seem to be any way to use this together with the natural weak equivalences $QX \to X \to RX$ to derive the wanted result.
Another related statement is that $\text{Ho}C(X,Y) \cong C(QX,RY)/\sim$, but I don't see how this follow either.

Here is an answer with (I think) a gap in it. Maybe someone can fill in the gap. Edit: I think I've filled the gap.
We have $\operatorname{Ho} \mathsf{C}(X,Y) \cong \mathsf{C}(RQX,
RQY)/\!\sim \,$.
If we apply the natural transformation $\operatorname{id} \to R$ to $QX$, we get a trivial cofibration $QX \to RQX$. Since $RQY$ is fibrant, we then get (by 1.2.5) a bijection
$$
\mathsf{C}(RQX, RQY) / \!\sim \, \xrightarrow{\ \cong\ }  \mathsf{C}(QX, RQY) / \!\sim \,.
$$
If we apply $R$ to the weak equivalence $QY \to Y$, we get a map $RQY \to RY$ of fibrant objects, and this is a weak equivalence (this was the missing piece): we have a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
QY @>{\sim}>> Y \\
@V{\sim}VV @VV{\sim}V \\
RQY @>{?}>> RY
\end{CD}
$$
The top arrow is a weak equivalence by assumption, and the vertical arrows are weak equivalences because that's how the natural transformation $\operatorname{id} \to R$ works. Therefore the bottom arrow is a weak equivalence by 2-out-of-3.
Thus since $QX$ is cofibrant, 1.2.5 gives bijection
$$
\mathsf{C}(QX, RQY) / \!\sim \, \xrightarrow{\ \cong\ } \mathsf{C}(QX, QY) / \!\sim \,.
$$
Composing would then give
$$
\mathsf{C}(RQX, RQY) / \!\sim \, \xrightarrow{\ \cong\ }  \mathsf{C}(QX, QY) / \!\sim \,.
$$
If $X$ is cofibrant and $Y$ is fibrant, then 1.2.5 gives us bijections
$$
\mathsf{C}(X,Y)/\!\sim \, \xrightarrow{\ \cong\ } \mathsf{C}(X, RY) / \!\sim \, \xrightarrow{\ \cong \ } \mathsf{C}(QX, RY) / \!\sim \,.
$$
For example, $X$ is cofibrant and $Y \to RY$ is a weak equivalence of fibrant objects, so we get the first bijection.
